# OAuth client to Azure Active Directory receives AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I have registered a web application in Azure Active Directory. The goal of this app (platform) is to be an external claims provider for conditional access, invoked via a custom control.

As a result, the application has the following Delegated "Required permissions":

- Access the directory as the signed-in user
- Read directory data (this requires admin approval)

I have also flagged the app as Multi-tenanted in Properties so that other Azure AD tenants can grant access to it to read their directories (this is how I intend to be an external claims provider).

The current issue is that after the administrator of a target Azure AD tenant grants access to my app, and redirects back to my app with an authorization code, I always get an error attempting to exchange the authorization code for a token response. The error is a 500, with body like:

```
{
  "error":"server_error",
  "error_description":"AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials.\r\nTrace ID: c2d3fe4d-8801-4ef7-b264-5b7fbd091f00\r\nCorrelation ID: f2ae5587-43cd-4c9e-bd58-0b776c0e7cf5\r\nTimestamp: 2018-08-08 08:55:25Z",
  "error_codes":[70002],
  "timestamp":"2018-08-08 08:55:25Z",
  "trace_id":"c2d3fe4d-8801-4ef7-b264-5b7fbd091f00",
  "correlation_id":"f2ae5587-43cd-4c9e-bd58-0b776c0e7cf5"
}
```

I am sure the client_id (my AppID), client_secret (a key I created), redirect_uri, grant_type and code are all correct.

I just have no idea why I'm getting a 500 from the token endpoint without any detail as to what is really wrong with my code->token exchange.

I should add that I am using the "common" authorize and token endpoints (but have also tried my tenant versions as well with no change in behaviour):

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token
```

Comment: Ensure in the body of the request you are mentioning all of these values - client_id, grant_type (as authorization_code), scope, code, redirect_uri, client_secret